# I recovered some encrypted pictures, but I can't decrypt them

Tags: sd-card, encryption, files, images

My girlfriend lost all the pictures from our holidays. She has a Samsung Galaxy A70. She had an external encrypted SD card on it. I managed to recover the lost pictures, but they are encrypted. Do you have any idea what I can do?

I've tried putting back the pictures, and then decrypting the SD but it doesn't work.

Comment: *"I managed to recover the lost pictures, but they are encrypted*" please elaborate

Comment: Thanks, of course. The phone simply deleted all the images from the SD starting January 1st. I recovered the files with Diskdrill. I can see the date and time when the picture was taken but can't open them.

Comment: adoptable-storage can be FDE or FBE

Comment: The encryption was the one that Android uses on the SD card.

Comment: sorry that is too broad. don't know what you have done, but most likely it's pointless

Comment: Cool, thanks. I have no idea which one of them I'll check that and edit the post. Thanks again.

Comment: This is one reason why I recommend not encrypting data unless you have a reason to do so.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket this is no different from the cases where a hard drive of a PC ends up corrupting very badly. The solution is regular and encrypted backups for both cases. It is not easy to do if one cannot afford additional offline/online storage, but it is reliable.